# Installed self-signed server certificate causes TrustFailure in Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, tls1.2

I have a Xamarin.Android app, and I have the self-signed certification of the *server* installed on the Android device (it was installed using the built-in user certification installer).

[image]

When I *disable* server certification validation, the client can connect to the server.

```
 if (!sslCheck)
          System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
```

When I want the TLS connection to be used, I always get the following exception:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request 
---> System.Net.WebException: Error: TrustFailure (One or more errors occurred.) 
---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. 
---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. 
---> Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: 
  Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
  at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-7/xamarin-android/external/mono/external/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.c:1132
  at Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsContext.ProcessHandshake () [0x00038] in <5a97d41d36694fb19855c17429527b10>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x0003e] in <5a97d41d36694fb19855c17429527b10>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake(Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus)
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncHandshakeRequest.Run (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x00006] in <5a97d41d36694fb19855c17429527b10>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest+<ProcessOperation>d__24.MoveNext () [0x000ff] in <5a97d41d36694fb19855c17429527b10>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest+<StartOperation>d__23.MoveNext () [0x0008b] in <5a97d41d36694fb19855c17429527b10>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream+<ProcessAuthentication>d__47.MoveNext () [0x00254] in <5a97d41d36694fb19855c17429527b10>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00043] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait () [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x0000d] in <5a97d41d36694fb19855c17429527b10>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MonoTlsStream.CreateStream (System.Byte[] buffer) [0x0007b] in <5a97d41d36694fb19855c17429527b10>:0 
  at System.Net.WebConnection.CreateStream (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x00073] in <5a97d41d36694fb19855c17429527b10>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00058] in <5a97d41d36694fb19855c17429527b10>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__64.MoveNext () [0x0041d] in <996a681f30a44cd685a4da54e11956e2>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__64.MoveNext () [0x00478] in <996a681f30a44cd685a4da54e11956e2>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>d__49.MoveNext () [0x000ca] in <996a681f30a44cd685a4da54e11956e2>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at MyXamarinAndroid.MyClient+<DownloadData>d__8.MoveNext () [0x00140]
```

I have the following network security configuration in *AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<network-security-config>
  <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
      <certificates src="system" />
      <certificates src="user" />
    </trust-anchors>
  </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

This should allow my app to use *user-added* certificates and trust them.

**UPDATE**

When I change my *HttpClient implementation* to *Android*:

[image]

I get the following Exception:

```
Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. 
---> Java.Security.Cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. 
---> Java.Security.Cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <7802aa64ad574c33adca332a3fa9706a>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00014] in <7802aa64ad574c33adca332a3fa9706a>:0 
  at Javax.Net.Ssl.HttpsURLConnectionInvoker.Connect () [0x0000a] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+<>c__DisplayClass42_0.<ConnectAsync>b__0 () [0x0005a] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+<DoProcessRequest>d__44.MoveNext () [0x0012e] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__39.MoveNext () [0x0022c] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>d__49.MoveNext () [0x000ca] in <996a681f30a44cd685a4da54e11956e2>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at MyXamarinAndroid.MyClient+<DownloadData>d__8.MoveNext () [0x000d2]  
  --- End of managed Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException stack trace ---
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:219)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:299)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:237)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source:0)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:661)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:539)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:495)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:418)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:339)
    at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
    at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:197)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:399)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.SslWrapper.doHandshake(SslWrapper.java:374)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:217)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    ... 24 more
```

What else should I set?

Comment: try this?
"cert-sync --user /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"  
                                                                                                                          
   from https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44963

Comment: @AnyMoose Thanks, but there are some circumstances. First, I'm not a root user on the device and I can't run that command (I'm also not familiar with it). Second, it says that the issue has been fixed in version 4.8, I use 4.10.